# How to disable scrolling property of expandable list view in android?

Tags: android, scroll, expandablelistview

Is it possible to disable scrolling property of expandable list view in android through xml or code??

Answer (score 0):

I think that is impossible because the view is automatically set to vertically scrolling list just like ListView, since ExpandableListView inherits ListView.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/activity_expandable_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <!-- your code --->

     <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/activity_expandable_list_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"/>


    enter code here
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

// In java code

```
mListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.activity_expandable_list_view);
        MyExpandableListAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(this,
                mGroups);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, long id) {
                setListViewHeight(parent, groupPosition);
                return false;
            }
        });



private void setListViewHeight(ExpandableListView listView,
                               int group) {
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter = (ExpandableListAdapter) listView.getExpandableListAdapter();
    int totalHeight = 0;
    int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(),
            View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
        View groupItem = listAdapter.getGroupView(i, false, null, listView);
        groupItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

        totalHeight += groupItem.getMeasuredHeight();

        if (((listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i != group))
                || ((!listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i == group))) {
            for (int j = 0; j < listAdapter.getChildrenCount(i); j++) {
                View listItem = listAdapter.getChildView(i, j, false, null,
                        listView);
                listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

                totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

            }
        }
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    int height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getGroupCount() - 1));
    if (height < 10)
        height = 200;
    params.height = height;
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();

}
```